# In C#, how can I consolidate or even remove two C# classes which are almost poltergeists?

Tags: c#, salesforce, refactoring, bulkinsert, code-duplication

I have two classes:

```
    public class UploadedBankData : BankData {

        [DataMember(Name = "sf__Id")]
        public new string SalesforceId {
            get => base.SalesforceId;
            set => base.SalesforceId = value;
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "sf__Created")]
        public bool SalesforceCreated { get; set; }

    }
```

and

```
    public class UploadedPersonAccount : PersonAccount {

        [DataMember(Name = "sf__Id")]
        public new string SalesforceId {
            get => base.SalesforceId;
            set => base.SalesforceId = value;
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "sf__Created")]
        public bool SalesforceCreated { get; set; }

    }
```

As you can see, other than the name of the class and the class they extend, both classes are identical.

These classes only exist because I am using `ServiceStack.Text` to transform the base class into a CSV, upload the CSV to Salesforce over Bulk API 2.0 **(for which the SaleforceId must be annotated with `[IgnoreDataMember]` or the upload will *FAIL*)** and then retrieve the newly created records with the newly generated SalesforceIds which will be assigned back to the appropriate records with the following code:

```
        public Dictionary<string, T> Update<T, TU>(Dictionary<string, T> oldSObjectBySalesforceAccountId, RelayerContext context)
        where TU : T
        where T : AlternativeIdentifiable {
            IConfiguration config = context.Config;
            string url = $"{config["SalesforceInstanceBaseUrl"]}/services/data/{config["SalesforceVersion"]}/jobs/ingest/{context.job.Id}/successfulResults";

            this.restClient.Get(url, context.token)
            .FromCsv<List<AlternativeIdentifiable>>()
            .ForEach((updatedBankData) => {
                if (oldSObjectBySalesforceAccountId.TryGetValue(updatedBankData.GetAlternativeId(), out T oldSObject)) {
                    oldSObject.SalesforceId = updatedBankData.SalesforceId;
                }
            });

            return oldSObjectBySalesforceAccountId;
        }
```

As this solution may eventually support additional SObjects, this would be a lot of nearly identical classes to create an maintain.

Is there a better way?

Comment: So, do you want to avoid the identical classes with different names? Or improve their processing?

Comment: There is [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you want to improve working code. Make sure to explain what you are doing and why exactly, we aren't solving riddles here or there.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, Yes, I want to avoid the identical classes.  If there is a way to improve the processing, that could be interesting as well, but that's not what I am presently looking for.

Comment: @Sinatr, thank you for informing me of codereview, but why do you feel this is a riddle or that what I am doing is somehow unclear?

Comment: It's not clear what is your problem exactly, what exactly you want to be fixed. And to me (who never used salesforce or did builkinserts) is not clear what you did and why it was needed. Without those tags, I'd just say to move all such properties into base class.

Comment: @Sinatr, as my edit emphasizes, in the base class this value must be ignored (as in not contained in the CSV which `ServiceStack.Text` produces) or the upload will fail.

Comment: How about codegeneration? You can use T4 templates, where such classes generated (`partial class` if you need customization on top).

Comment: @Sinatr, "codegeneralization" sounds very good... I'm rather new to C#... it might help and be certainly be greatly a if you could demonstrate how I'd use the partial class to do this.

Comment: Google for "c# T4", [here](https://tim-maes.com/2019/03/28/t4-beginner-tutorial/) is some tutorial. I am not sure if idea is good enough. They are useful for synchronizing (by re-generating) one form of data based on another, e.g. generating C# class with constants out of C header file. If it's just two classes with two properties it's not worth it. If there are dozens of similar properties, repeated in different classes it may be very good.

Comment: Right now it is just two classes, but there is at least one more on the horizon and in the future there are potentially countless SObjects I may need to support, each of which would currently need another base class and another extension class.  Also, there will actually be at least one more property I'd need to support for fetching errors.